# Android Inapp purchase Subscription verification

Tags: android

How should one verify that the subscribed item he haas buyied using google play services,is still valid
I have buyied a magazine with monthly subscription ,
i got the :
{
    "orderId":"****",
    "packageName":"**** ",
    "productId":"77",
    "purchaseTime":****,
    "purchaseState":0,
    "purchaseToken":"****"
}

now how to know next time whether i have buyied the item without calling playservices.
Is there any api to check the subscription is still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google developer's guide sais:

> purchaseState: The purchase state of the order. Possible values are 0 (purchased), 1 (canceled), or 2 (refunded).

Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html).

So yout subscription is still active and you will pay again, if you do not cancel it in time.

The purchaseTime is the time you bought the item - made the subscription. In Google Play you can see if it is a monthly or annualy subscription. Use there infos to calculate the time you pay for it the next time.

Comment: Is there any php script for verifying android in app subscription

Comment: and thanks for your help i have already implemented the above but with further requirements i am stuck ,i want to know the subscription status from my server.

Comment: @DhirajHimani There is a [PurchaseSstatus API](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html)

Comment: I have applied this and i am getting the results but i want a php script for getting results on my server

Comment: Thanks for your help,I used the PHP script provided by the google and the inapp purchase info from the android purchase.It solved it :)